# Force SSL Everywhere

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl

I don't really know what is going on or anything, but I want to make my entire site done in Codeigniter, to be SSL encrypted, EVERYWHERE, but the problem is, I have the base_url in the config set to https://www.mysite.com/

But when I load it up, it shows that the page is unsecure (the red crossed out https on chrome)

I made sure all the images on the page, all the included css/js files, are all using the https as well, and I still get that error...

Comment: Look in the Network panel and see if any resources (hint: Ajax?) are being requested on an insecure connection.

Comment: What is the URL you're typing in the address bar?

Comment: @Matthew - in chrome that means the page is using SSL but the pages is pulling in elements that are not over SSL

Comment: @minitech - After looking at it, there were non that were being requested on an insecure connection, they were all being used by HTTPS

Comment: Are you requesting any external assets, like javascript libraries hosted elsewhere?

Comment: Do you have a trusted certificate?

Comment: What is the error that chrome shows up? Does the error mean that there are certain resources which are being requested or that chrome doesn't trust the certificate being requested. A screenshot / error text will help here.

Comment: nothing showing up in the network tab as red?  sometimes when you do http from https or vice versa it takes over 20 seconds to show the error as it has to time out first.

Comment: So, from your site (which is running under HTTPs), you are requesting resources over HTTP and you see the error only after the connection times out. Is that issue? If so, have you checked the connectivity between both the machines?